# NetExtender: Unable to reconnect

Tags: linux, vpn, sonicwall

I am running NetExtender on my Linux based server to connect to the another company's private network.
The connection works fine but once in a month, if the connection drops it does not reconnect automatically.
The program is configured to automatically reconnect when the connection is terminated, It tries to reconnect but no success.

if I manually log in to the server and close the netextender then restart, it works fine but I need this program up and running at all times.

Below is the log when it disconnected

```
08/20/2014 08:46:59.538 [connect error   20617] SSL_read ZERO RETURN
08/20/2014 08:46:59.538 [general notice  20617] SSL VPN logging out...
08/20/2014 08:46:59.552 [connect info    24510] NetExtender interface down
08/20/2014 08:46:59.554 [dns     notice  24510] Restoring DNS settings
08/20/2014 08:46:59.604 [general notice  20617] SSL VPN connection is terminated.
08/20/2014 08:46:59.605 [config  info    20617] Loading saved profiles...
08/20/2014 08:46:59.605 [config  info    20617] Loaded profile: sslvpn.companyname.co.uk
08/20/2014 08:46:59.605 [config  info    20617] Done.
08/20/2014 08:46:59.609 [gui     info    20617] NetExtender disconnected
08/20/2014 08:46:59.611 [connect info    20617] User:   "userID"
08/20/2014 08:46:59.611 [connect info    20617] Domain: "SSLVPN"
08/20/2014 08:46:59.611 [connect info    20617] Server: "sslvpn.companyname.co.uk:443"
08/20/2014 08:46:59.615 [general info    20617] Saving profiles/preferences...
08/20/2014 08:46:59.615 [general info    20617] Done saving profiles/preferences
08/20/2014 08:46:59.649 [general notice  20617] Connecting to sslvpn.companyname.co.uk:443...
08/20/2014 08:46:59.686 [connect warn    20617] SSL_get_peer_certificate: X509_V_ERR_INVALID_CA
08/20/2014 08:46:59.744 [general notice  20617] Connected.
08/20/2014 08:46:59.744 [general notice  20617] Logging in...
08/20/2014 08:47:00.170 [general info     6267] nxMonitor received shutdown command; nxMonitor exiting
08/20/2014 08:47:06.876 [general notice  20617] Login successful.
08/20/2014 08:47:06.958 [general error   20617] failed to retrieve epc agent version
08/20/2014 08:47:06.959 [epc     info    20617] Server don't support EPC check. Just pass EPC check
08/20/2014 08:47:07.020 [general error   20617] unexpected response while retriving session ID
08/20/2014 08:47:07.020 [general notice  20617] No routes found.  Checking for legacy route format...
08/20/2014 08:47:07.104 [general error   20617] unexpected response while retriving server route
08/20/2014 08:47:07.104 [general error   20617] Connection failure
08/20/2014 08:47:07.104 [general notice  20617] SSL VPN logging out...
08/20/2014 08:47:07.167 [general notice  20617] SSL VPN connection is terminated.
08/20/2014 08:47:07.168 [config  info    20617] Loading saved profiles...
08/20/2014 08:47:07.168 [config  info    20617] Loaded profile: sslvpn.companyname.co.uk
08/20/2014 08:47:07.168 [config  info    20617] Done.
08/20/2014 08:47:07.172 [gui     info    20617] Failed to connect
```

Is this a problem with my server or there is something wrong with their server which is why i gets disconnected? 
Can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sometime disconnects just happen, but the client should be able to reconnect every time.  I think it's an issue with the NetExtender client.  We've had issues with it on Linux before, and the only fix is to wait for Sonicwall to issue an updated client!

Since manually restarting it works, maybe a work-around is to use a monitoring service (like Monit) to check the connection?  For example, Monit could ping something on the other end of the tunnel every minute.  If there is no response, Monit could kill and re-initiate the connection. http://mmonit.com/monit/

An example monit config would be

```
check host myserver with address 192.168.1.1
  if failed icmp type echo count 2 with timeout 10 seconds then restart
  start program = "/bin/bash /home/me/netextender-startup-script.sh"
  stop program =  "/bin/bash /home/me/netextender-stop-script.sh"
```

You'd have to define the startup and stop scripts based on your Linux distro...